# why are values in object updated on submit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

Every Time a user submits the form, the data related to that task gets stored in an object and that object gets passed into an array which holds list of tasks.

[Image to the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWTgP.png)

Now when you log the tasksList array to console. each task gets the same value of "date". Values for all the instance of a tasks are overwritten. I want the object to have seperate values of "date" for each person.

// app component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ITaskDetails } from './interfaces/task-details';
import { TaskService } from './services/task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  currentDate: {};
  taskForm: FormGroup;
  taskArr: ITaskDetails[];
  taskObj: ITaskDetails = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    date: null
  };

  constructor(private taskSer: TaskService) {
    this.currentDate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.taskForm = new FormGroup({
      'taskTitle': new FormControl(''),
      'description': new FormControl(''),
      'date': new FormControl(this.currentDate)
    });
    console.log(this.taskForm);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.taskObj.title = this.taskForm.get('taskTitle').value;
    this.taskObj.description = this.taskForm.get('description').value;
    this.taskObj.date = this.taskForm.get('date').value;

    console.log(this.taskObj);

    this.taskSer.setData({...this.taskObj});
    this.taskArr = this.taskSer.getdata();
    console.log(this.taskArr);
  }
}
```

// Task Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ITaskDetails } from '../interfaces/task-details';

@Injectable()
export class TaskService {
  taskArr: ITaskDetails[] = [];
  taskDetails = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    date: null
  };

  setData(obj: ITaskDetails) {
    this.taskDetails.title = obj.title;
    this.taskDetails.description = obj.description;
    this.taskDetails.date = obj.date;
    this.taskArr.push(this.taskDetails);
  }
  getdata() {
    return this.taskArr;
  }
  constructor() { }

}
```

// form template

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Add a Task</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="taskForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title *</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskTitle" placeholder="Title of Task" formControlName="taskTitle">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description *</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter Your Description" formControlName="description">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date of Completion *</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" formControlName="date">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-offset-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!taskForm.valid">Submit your data</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <app-task-list></app-task-list>
</section>
```

Comment: Remove the spread operator it copies the object properties into duplicate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: from this line `this.taskSer.setData({...this.taskObj});`

Comment: thanks for the reference @Niladri. Sorry cant upvote not privileged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to spread your taskDetails object in your service method like this

```
setData(obj: ITaskDetails) {
    this.taskDetails.title = obj.title;
    this.taskDetails.description = obj.description;
    this.taskDetails.date = obj.date;
    this.taskArr.push({...this.taskDetails}); <<<<<this
}
```

not when you are calling the method and passing the object. Remove the spread object form

```
onSubmit() {
    this.taskObj.title = this.taskForm.get('taskTitle').value;
    this.taskObj.description = this.taskForm.get('description').value;
    this.taskObj.date = this.taskForm.get('date').value;

    console.log(this.taskObj);

    this.taskSer.setData({...this.taskObj}); <<<<this to setData(this.taskObj);
    this.taskArr = this.taskSer.getdata();
    console.log(this.taskArr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some "strange" width this.taskObj.title = this.taskForm.get('taskTitle').value;

use

```
this.taskObj.title = this.taskForm.value.taskTitle;
this.taskObj.title = this.taskForm.value.taskTitle;
this.taskObj.description = this.taskForm.value.description;
this.taskObj.date = this.taskForm.value.date;
```

or, better,

```
//change the submit as
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="taskForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(taskForm)">

//And in the onSubmit
onSubmit(dataForm: FormGroup) {
   if (dataForm.isValid)
   {
     this.taskObj.title = dataForm.value.taskTitle;
     ....
   }
}
```

Anyway, check in your service

```
setData(obj: ITaskDetails) {
   console.log(obj); //<--this
   ...
}
```

Comment: still the same error. and its a reactive form you dont need to pass the `taskForm` to onSubmit